# Adapter with IP for VPN and secondary IP for normal traffic (IP TABLES)

Tags: iptables, vpn, bash, routing, linux-networking

Can't figure out how to route my secondary IP to use my ip table "mytable" which have this setting :

```
    sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.255 dev enp5s0 table mytable
```

the table is set up in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

I am now trying to add the table to my secondary ip `192.168.1.113`
with this rule:

```
    sudo ip rule add from 192.168.1.113 table mytable
```

However, the command `ip -o route get 192.168.1.113` returns: `local 192.168.1.113 dev lo table local src 192.168.1.112`

Which i think is routing the secondary ip back to the VPN tunnel.
Extra info:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- router gateway, ip and dns: `192.168.1.254`
- Primary ip: `192.168.1.112`
- LAN adapter is `enp5s0`
- VPN is `tun0`
- ip r returns:

```
    0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0 
    default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
    -EXTERNAL_VPN_IP- via 192.168.1.254 dev enp5s0 
    10.8.1.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.2 
    128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0 
    169.254.0.0/16 dev enp5s0 scope link metric 1000 
    192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.112 metric 100 
    192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.113 metric 100
```

I've studied this [How to make Apache output packets through a certain network interface when connected to VPN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/794887/how-to-make-apache-output-packets-through-a-certain-network-interface-when-conne)

I think my problem is wrong route rules and maybe my router settings. I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use the ip route get command wrongly.

The correct command is `ip route get <dst> from 192.168.1.113`, where `<dst>` is an ip address of some external host (better run the tcpdump and take the ip from the dump).

Your rule is correct, and the command should return the route `192.168.1.255 dev enp5s0` from additional table.